# Orange Data Mining version 3.3 (Python) Association Rules

Tags: python-3.x, orange

Orange Data Mining version 2.7 (Python) has the following example for Association Rules:

```
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("market-basket.basket")

rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(data, support=0.3)
print "%4s %4s  %s" % ("Supp", "Conf", "Rule")
for r in rules[:5]:
    print "%4.1f %4.1f  %s" % (r.support, r.confidence, r)
```

However this does not work in Orange Data Mining version 3.3. How can I do this example in version 3.3?

`help(Orange)` was also not very helpful.

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'associate'
```

on:

```
rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(data, support=0.3)
```

Alternatively, when using the Association Rules widget in Oracle Canvas I'm not sure what widget can be used to display the output of the Association Rules widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Orange 3, the association rules had been moved into an add-on: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3-Associate

Documentation: https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html

It is used a bit differently and is in my experience much, much faster.

Comment: Helps, but sadly doesn't get me there. Examples seem very different.

Comment: Doesn't get you where? Examples work with item ids in numpy arrays or lists of lists. There's just a bit of hacking involved to get it to work with Orange tables (although I can't imagine why you'd want that). What problems are you facing?

Comment: I don't understand what the item id's mean.

Comment: The unique ids you assign to items. The simple case could be: `list(enumerate(all_possible_items))` (produces list of (`id`, `item`) pairs).